# "Failed to initialize the Common Language Runtime" when trying to access a SQL 2014 Express database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I'm currently developing a website that [uses](http://grammarpartyblog.com/2012/01/17/use-versus-utilize/) a SQL Server 2014 Express database on my machine. This has always worked in the past, but today I got the following error:

> Failed to initialize the Common Language Runtime (CLR) v4.0.30319 with
>   HRESULT 0x80131534. You need to restart SQL Server to use CLR
>   integration features.

Of course I restarted SQL Server 2014 Express, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downloading a [.NET framework repair tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135). After running it and rebooting my computer, I was able to connect to the database again.